# Word for "Formal Address"

Tags: одним-словом, formality

Question is about using **вы** instead of **ты**. I already know Serbian, so I know when you use one and when the other (Vi i Ti), what I'm interested in is, *how is this form of address called in Russian?*

In Serbian it's called "Persiranje" or as a verb "Persirati", but despite all Serbian/Russian similarities, the only word sounding like that I found was "пересирать" which is one step away from meaning the complete opposite :P

Comment: The word "пересирать" sounds like an indefinite form of "пересрать", a colloquial invective meaning either "to be scared a lot" or "to make a mess of (something)" depending on the context.

Comment: I guess "to be scared a lot" makes some sense

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: both are indefinite forms, the words differ in aspect (*пересирать* is imperfective, *пересрать* is perfective).

Comment: I believe there's no direct Russian equivalent. However, the verb you're looking for also exists in other languages, for instance, in French, it's "tutoyer".

Answer (score 10):

In a very formal way, formal address is called

1. `формальная форма обращения`, as opposed to
2. `фамильярная форма обращения`.

Colloquially these forms are known as

1. `на вы` and
2. `на ты`.

Answer (score 8):

*Persirati* apparently originates from German *per Sie*, *Sie* being the formal addressing in German.

In Russian there is a colloquial (single) verb *выкать*, or more formal phrase *быть на вы (с кем-либо)*:

> Мои подчиненные привыкли к тому, что они со мной на "ты", а я с ними на "вы". *[И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]*
>
> ― Пап, ты вождь и он вождь. Почему вы с ним на «вы»? ― Потому, что не ношу смазных сапог и не хожу на охоту. *[Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)]*

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for stab at origin :)
We also say "biti na vi" and "preći na ti"="перейти на ты"

Answer (score 6):

Well (if I get the question right), there are verbs `тыкать` and `выкать` (and, accordingly, nouns `тыканье` and `выканье`:

> Что вы мне тыкаете! Я с вами на брудершафт не пила

Those words are pretty informal and can be used only in casual speech. 
More formal it is called `обращение на ты/вы`.

Comment: Yes, you understood the question. I also liked the example. We also refer to these forms of address as Tikanje i Vikanje, but to us that's more like a joke. Well, maybe there's no such a word, thanks for your help.

Comment: @mimosveta, you're very welcome) as far as I know,  персирање is quite unique word that actually have no analogues in many other languages, including Slavic )

Comment: Yes, I did notice it's virtually impossible to translate to any other language I thought of :S

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться на ты/вы or быть [с кем-л.] на ты/вы are complete equivalents, not necessarily colloquial. I don't think it matters a lot whether it's a verb or a verb phrase.